# Pagination in MySQL with JOINed ORDER clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pagination

Having some trouble with paginating a dataset which is built by querying a joined table.

My product table looks like this:

```
id   | sort_order
-----------------
1    | 5
2    | 4
3    | 0
4    | 0
5    | 4
...
```

and my joined stock table looks like this:

```
id | product_id | start_date
----------------------------
1  | 1          | 2018-12-14
2  | 1          | 2019-01-28
3  | 2          | 2018-12-26
4  | 3          | 2018-12-28
5  | 4          | 2019-01-12
6  | 4          | 2019-01-14
7  | 5          | 2020-01-10
...
```

I would like to paginate my list of products, however, I would like to sort it as follows:

- Firstly, by `sort_order`
- Secondly, by the earliest `start_date` associated to it.

I initially started with `cursor pagination`, but this was resulting in duplicate results, although the total number of pages (after cursoring to the end) was correct - this meant that there must have been missing rows which were never fetched.

I then resorted to page based pagination (which would also be fine for now), but this is resulting in duplication also, and a huge number of pages.

I'm quite stuck as to how to continue with this.

My offset-based pagination `SQL` (generated by Sequelize) is below:

```
SELECT
    `Product`.`id` AS `id`,
    `Product`.`sort_order` AS `sortOrder`,
    `availability`.`id` AS `availability.id`,
    `availability`.`product_id` AS `availability.productId`,
    `availability`.`start_date` AS `availability.startDate`
FROM
    `product` AS `Product`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `stock` AS `availability` 
                 ON `Product`.`id` = `availability`.`productId`
ORDER BY
    sort_order = 0,
    sort_order
LIMIT 0, 10
```

With the dataset above, I would hope for the following:

```
id   | sortOrder | `availability.id` | `startDate`
--------------------------------------------------
1    | 5         | 1                 | 2018-12-14
2    | 4         | 3                 | 2018-12-26
5    | 4         | 7                 | 2020-01-10
3    | 0         | 4                 | 2018-12-28
4    | 0         | 5                 | 2019-01-12
```

Comment: What would be expected result based on the given sample dataset ? Please add that to the question.

Comment: done - it should pick the soonest available date to associate with the product, and not list the same product again. If the dataset were to continue, it would not repeat the product in a future page.

Comment: @AntonyJones I've updated my answer and demo based on your new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting duplication because you're `JOIN`ing to a table which has multiple values per `product_id`. You need to restrict that to one value, and based on your sort criteria that should be the values associated with the minimum start_date. You can do that with a subquery for the `JOIN` table:

```
SELECT
    `Product`.`id` AS `id`,
    `Product`.`sort_order` AS `sortOrder`,
    `availability`.`id` AS `availability.id`,
    `availability`.`product_id` AS `availability.productId`,
    `availability`.`start_date` AS `availability.start_date`
FROM
    `product` AS `Product`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, product_id, start_date
           FROM`stock` s
           WHERE start_date = (SELECT MIN(start_date) 
                               FROM stock s1 
                                WHERE s1.product_id = s.product_id)
           ) AS `availability` 
    ON `Product`.`id` = `availability`.`product_id`
ORDER BY
    sort_order = 0,
    sort_order,
    availability.start_date
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Output for your sample data:

```
id  sortOrder   availability.id     availability.productId  availability.start_date
1   5           1                   1                       2018-12-14
2   4           3                   2                       2018-12-26
5   4           7                   5                       2020-01-10
3   0           4                   3                       2018-12-28
4   0           5                   4                       2019-01-12
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63a327/2)

Comment: This is excellent - I've tested it and it should work with offset pagination. Am I right in assuming that because I don't have a unique, consecutive ID field in the result-set, this won't work with cursor pagination, only offset pagination?

Comment: @AntonyJones I think you're right, but you could probably use MySQL variables to generate a unique, consecutive id